# How to return data from a joined table

Tags: php, mysql

The purpose behind this, is for me to be able to extract data from a table thats been formed via INNER JOIN of two other tables.

I've mapped a tariff name to a username successfully. But what i want to do is to be able to return data from this new table that was created via INNER JOIN in a text field on android studio.

My main concern at the moment is figuring out the right query to do be able to return the data. I've tried researching this but have had no luck/
I have 2 databases. A **useraccount** database and a **tariff** database.

useraccount database consists of the following columns:

ID
Name
Surname
EmailAddress
PostCode
City
PhoneNumber
Username
Password
ConfirmPassword 
tariffs

And my Tariff database consists of the following column:

ID
Name

I have joined the two tables using INNER JOIN, and have linked the username column with the tariff name column, essentially, i ended up with a table like this:

Username|Tariff

Here is the code for that:

```
$query = "SELECT useraccount.Username, tariff.Name as tariffs
FROM useraccount
INNER JOIN tariff ON useraccount.tariffs = tariff.id";  

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if($result->num_rows){
        while($row = $result ->fetch_object()){
            echo "{$row->Username} ({$row->tariffs}) <br>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "No results";

    }


    $query2 = "SELECT";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
```

Question:

How do I access the columns of the result set?

[This image shows the result of the execution of the PHP file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLbqL.png)

Comment: are you trying to join records from different tables in different databases?  Its not 100% clear to me what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, not quite, what I'm trying to do is link two tables; the useraccount table, and tariff table, in doing so, i am able to map the username column from the useraccount table to the tariff name in the tariff column. Essentially, each user is assigned a tariff name. What i then want to do with this, is to be able to return a tariff name for a particular user in my app. Hence i've joined the two tables to create that link.

Comment: what is populated in the $result object?  If you execute this directly on the database do you get records?

Comment: "what I'm trying to do is link two tables" - but that's what you've done in your code example.  I'm not clear on what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: So,  the $result object contains the attributes:  Username: absc868 and Tariff Name: s1. I have executed it, ill add a screen shot of the result in the op

Comment: @ethan, apologies for the confusion, what i meant to say was, by joining the two tables, a third table is created correct? The joined table. From this joined table i want to be able to write a query where i can return values from it. So for example, the joined table will consist of just the username and tariff name. I want to be able to return the tariff name and the username from this table. Apologies if its still not clear.

Comment: You have created a result set that is a combination of the two.

Comment: @MisterPositive Yes that is correct. Now, i want to be able to return the data from this third table thats been created. However, im not sure how to go about doing that because a SELECT statement requires you to specify the table name. But this third table has no name. I hope that made sense lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining two tables together does not create a third table, but creates a **result set** from the combined records of the two tables.  In your code example, you already have access to all the data contained in the useraccounts and tariff tables.  To gain access to this data, simply modify your select statement so that it references the desired columns.  You could also just use the '*' wildcard to include all columns in your result set.

```
 // Using a wildcard to get all useraccount data. 
$query = "SELECT useraccount.*, tariff.Name as tariffs
FROM useraccount
INNER JOIN tariff ON useraccount.tariffs = tariff.id"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if($result->num_rows){
    while($row = $result ->fetch_object()){      
        // Reference any user data you want.
        echo "{$row->Username} {$row->EmailAddress} {$row->PostCode} ({$row->tariffs}) <br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not get exactly what he was after

Comment: @MisterPositive took me a second too :)

Comment: @ethan ah ok, i see thank you so much ethan, i understand now :)

Comment: @Mahbs Good, I'm glad that helped!  If you feel this answered your question, please consider marking it as the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to join the user account id on the tariff id:

```
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "username";
 $password = "password";
 $dbname = "myDB";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

 $sql = "SELECT useraccount.Username, tariff.Name FROM useraccount INNER JOIN tariff ON useraccount.id = tariff.id";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Username: " . $row["username"]. " - Tarrif: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Hi @Hexana, i have successfully been able to join the table. The issue is, how do i return the data that is contained in this third table thats been created via joining the useraccount table and the tariff table. Note: The third table contains the username column and the tariff name column, i want to return data present in these columns

Comment: I've updated my answer as to how I would do it.  Hope it helps